# java regex - not able to retrieve contents from first square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am pretty new to regular expressions stuff.. I have this requirement of picking up contents in the first square brackets.
 For e.g. if I have the string like 
"PORT-OTEF_RA2/6 [Eh0001/001-06] [ignore, test port]", 
 
I need the result as  "Eh0001/001-06".

I am using following regular expression.

```
Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile("^PORT.+\\[(.*?)\\]");

    Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher("PORT-OTEF_RA2/6 [Eh0001/001-06] [ignore, test port]");

if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

but I always get the contents of second square brackets. 
However, if I give the regular expression as

```
Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

I get the required answer. But I need to make sure the string starts with "PORT". Can someone light me on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use non-greedy regex after `PORT`:

```
^PORT.+?\\[(.*?)\\]
```

Otherwise `.+` will be greedy and match till last `[...]` is found.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uA2jI4/1)